# This with addEventListener

Tags: javascript

Hey guys am new to javascript..and i have been learning the use of this in javascript and i found that the value of `this` keyword depends upon how the function was called..But the code from `mdn` confuses me ..The code is ..

```
var Something = function(element) {

  this.name = 'Something Good';

    this.onclick1 = function(event) {

    console.log(this.name);

};

  this.onclick2 = function(event) {

  console.log(this.name); 

 };

  element.addEventListener('click', this.onclick2.bind(this), false); 

}
```

when i call the function with `var b = new something(param)` it works well ..I know now the value of `this` will be b..But when i redited the same code with `window` on the place of `this`..like `window.onclick2.bind(window)`.It gives the same input .I dont know why they are giving me the same output..Whats the actualy value of `this` here ??

Hope you can make me understand ...

Comment: I'm a bit confused. What output are you getting, and what did you expect?

Comment: i need to know the value of this here ..??..what this corresponds to ??

Comment: It's a new object created when you called `new Something()`. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new

Comment: so the new object is the value of this ..right ??

Answer (score 0):

There is principle known as use-that-not-this, which prevents the issue you have. The idea is to "remembers: **this** within a current scope and you don't depend on a scope anymore. I suggest you to check these links:
[link1](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/this.html)
[link2](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this)

I've just implemented for you this [sample](http://jsfiddle.net/wDp2y/5/) for simplicity:

```
var Something2 = function (element) {
    //in this way you have just defined variable in the same context as Something and Something2
    window.someProperty = 'Something Good 2'; 
    window.onclick2 = function (event) {
        alert(window.someProperty);
    };
    element.addEventListener('click', window.onclick2.bind(window), false);
}

var input2 = document.getElementById("input2");
var b = new Something2(input2);
```

Now, both cases works for you, but in the second approach (by using window instead of this), you introduced a variable **someProperty** in global window context. You can check this by calling:

```
alert(typeof(someProperty));
```

Let me know if you need further explanations

Comment: i have read those links before ...i didnt get anything ..tell me what you get from here ...is this represents window or b ?

Comment: accrding to their docs they say Inside a function, the value of this depends on how the function is called...so it must be b here ??

Comment: Ok, it depends on execution scope, i.e. from where you execute your code. The top most scope (global) belongs to window itself, but if your code would be executed from within event handler of html element, i.e. assigned as "element.onclick = doSomething", this will have different meaning and will be scoped to the element

Comment: i need to know the value of this here ..??..what this corresponds to ?? still i didnt get it

Comment: Now I am confused: which value of "this" you want to know if you've just replaced it with "window"? The statement "var b = new Something2(input2);" will instantiate for you new object, clone the prototype and call it's constructor and roughly speaking "this" inside the function Something2 will be associated with context of variable "b". But need to mention that saying it in such way is not really correct and confusing

Comment: so the new object b  is the value of this  keyword ..right ??